# Microsoft Dynamics Nav2009 closed immediately when i try to run

Tags: .net, microsoft-dynamics, navision

This is the Error details from the Event Viewer:

Type: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Message: The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' registered for extension 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior' could not be loaded. (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config line 192)
BareMessage: The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' registered for extension 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior' could not be loaded.
Filename: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config
Line: 192
StackTrace:
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetSectionFromConfigurationManager(String sectionPath)
at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetAssociatedSection(ContextInformation evalContext, String sectionPath)
at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CommonBehaviorsSection.UnsafeGetSection()
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupCommonBehaviors(ContextInformation context)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadCommonClientBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint)
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(Binding binding, EndpointAddress address)
at System.ServiceModel.DuplexChannelFactory`1..ctor(Object callbackObject, Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress) at System.ServiceModel.DuplexChannelFactory`1..ctor(InstanceContext callbackInstance, Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.ServiceConnection.Initialize()
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.ServiceConnection.OpenConnectionInternal(ConnectFailedEventArgs connectFailedArg)
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.ServiceConnection.OpenConnection()
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.FormBuilder.BuilderSession.Initialize()
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.UISession.Initialize()
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.Windows.ClientSessionBase.SetupUISession()
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.Windows.ClientSessionBase.Init()
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.Program.MainCore(String[] args)
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
Source: System.Configuration

Answer (score 1):

It could be an error use by **Windows Update**. Try to restart the server if there was an update recently.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Install the latest version of .net and if possible update your Nav service account to the latest version available. sometimes is te service doesn't have the same version as the client, that happens. a downgrade of the version may work, depending of what you updated before the crash.

Option 2:
A table might be modified recently, so when you ran the client it didn't fount the right indexes. Open Nav in a classic mode, then go to objects and sort by date modified, you should see a recent modified object.